# Name for using a big word where a small word would suffice?

Tags: single-word-requests

I read this definition when I was about 10 or 12. I forgot the word and have been looking ever since. I think I remember it starting with the letter "s".

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the adjective [sesquipedalian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sesquipedalian). Merriam-Webster defines it as "having many syllables" (when used of words) or "given to or characterized by the use of long words" (when used of people).

There's also a noun sesquipedalianism.

Comment: I first came across that word in connection with CEM Joad.